# React Native - Expo: Invariant Violation: Nesting of <View> within <Text> is not currently supported

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I upgraded my react native project created with CRNA.
Project was running just fine on iOS before the upgrade but I had some issues when loading it on an android device/emulator and I was hoping the upgrade would solve them.
I upgraded expo from version 27.0.1 to 31.0.4,
I read through the whole:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough
to check for any breaking changes.

I went, step-by-step through upgrading expo:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v31.0.0/workflow/upgrading-expo

Old package.json:

```
{
  "name": "FamScore3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/auth": "^0.7.6",
    "@firebase/database": "^0.3.6",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "firebase": "^5.5.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Old app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "27.0.0"
  }
}
```

Upgraded package.json:

```
{
  "name": "FamScore3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
    "jest-expo": "^31.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/auth": "^0.7.6",
    "@firebase/database": "^0.3.6",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.45.0",
    "expo": "^31.0.4",
    "firebase": "^5.5.1",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Upgraded app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "31.0.0"
  }
}
```

After the upgrade was complete, I reinstalled the expo app on my iPhone 6s. I cleared the cache in expo. Shut down the expo packager and terminal and rebooted my computer.

Now the app is throwing errors on both iOS and Android.
On iOS i get the error:

[Error received on physical device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE9nU.jpg)

Where the first error is located(the Icon-related):

```
<Button style={styles.buttonStyle} textStyle={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={() => this.authUser()}>
            <Icon
              iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
              size={iconSize}
              color={'#ea8a8a'}
              type='simple-line-icon'
              name={'heart'}
            />
            Login
          </Button>
```

The Button used here is actually not imported from react-native but a custom one I made with the same name(probably a bad idea but hey):

```
class Button extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress} style={[styles.buttonStyle, this.props.style]}>
        <Text style={[styles.textStyle, this.props.textStyle]}>{this.props.children}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

export { Button }
```

This was never an issue before the update and I really can't seem to find what broke this code.
Any help would be much appreciated as I find myself running in circles over here.
If you want me to provide you with any additional code, I'll gladly do so.
Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button doesn't accept this syntax. If you need an icon in your button, try `TouchableHighlight` or similar:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{}}>
     <View>
         <Icon
              iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
              size={iconSize}
              color={'#ea8a8a'}
              type='simple-line-icon'
              name={'heart'}
            />
        <Text> Login </Text>
     </View>
 </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Oh sorry. Button is actually a custom component I made and not the default one from react-native. I have updated my question.
Thanks!

Comment: I just realised this solved my problem for iOS! Thanks a lot and have a great day! I'll make a new question regarding the Android issue.
Cheers!